# Running multiple parallel downloads in Android

Tags: android, android-service

First, I extended `IntentService` to build my `DonwloadService` class. It was OK, but a download queue had been created and 2nd download had to wait for the 1st to finished etc.

So I decided to extend `Service` class (following the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)). I've just added download function and function for publishing results (listened by receiver in activity):

```
    public class DownloadService extends Service
{
    private static final String TAG = DownloadService.class.getSimpleName();

    public static final String EXTRA_DOWNLOAD = "EXTRA_DOWNLOAD";
    public static final String EXTRA_POSITION = "EXTRA_POSITION";
    public static final String INTENT_NOTIFICATION = "INTENT_NOTIFICATION";
    public static final String EXTRA_RESULT = "EXTRA_RESULT";
    public static final String EXTRA_PROGRESS = "EXTRA_PROGRESS";
    public static final String EXTRA_PATH = "EXTRA_PATH";
    public static final String EXTRA_INDETERMINABLE = "EXTRA_INDETERMINABLE";
    public static final int RESULT_PROGRESS = 123;

    private int mResult = Activity.RESULT_CANCELED;

    private Looper mServiceLooper;
    private ServiceHandler mServiceHandler;

    private final class ServiceHandler extends Handler
    {
        public ServiceHandler(Looper looper)
        {
            super(looper);
        }

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message message)
        {
            // Download file
            download(message.getData());

            // Stop the service using the startId, so that we don't stop
            // the service in the middle of handling another job
            stopSelf(message.arg1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        // Start up the thread running the service.  Note that we create a
        // separate thread because the service normally runs in the process's
        // main thread, which we don't want to block.  We also make it
        // background priority so CPU-intensive work will not disrupt our UI.
        HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread("DownloadServiceStartArguments",
                Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
        handlerThread.start();

        // Get the HandlerThread's Looper and use it for our Handler
        mServiceLooper = handlerThread.getLooper();
        mServiceHandler = new ServiceHandler(mServiceLooper);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        // For each start request, send a message to start a job and deliver the
        // start ID so we know which request we're stopping when we finish the job
        Message message = mServiceHandler.obtainMessage();
        message.setData(intent.getExtras());
        message.arg1 = startId;
        mServiceHandler.sendMessage(message);

        return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
    {
        // No binding provided
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "Service done");
    }

    /**
     * Handles file download
     *
     * @param bundle
     */
    private void download(Bundle bundle)
    {
        if (bundle != null) {
            return;
        }

        Download download = bundle.getParcelable(EXTRA_DOWNLOAD);
        int position = bundle.getInt(EXTRA_POSITION, -1);

        File downloadedFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), position + ".jpg");
        if (downloadedFile.exists()) {
            downloadedFile.delete();
        }

        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;

        int filesize = -1;

        try {

            fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(downloadedFile.getPath());

            URL url = new URL(download.getUrl());
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();

            filesize = connection.getContentLength();

            InputStream reader = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());

            byte data[] = new byte[1024];

            int next = -1;
            int total = 0;
            while ((next = reader.read(data)) != -1) {
                mResult = RESULT_PROGRESS;
                total += next;
                publishResult(downloadedFile.getAbsolutePath(),
                        (filesize > 0) ? Math.round(total * 100 / filesize) : Math.round(total / 1024),
                        position, filesize <= 0);

                fileOutputStream.write(data, 0, next);
            }

            mResult = Activity.RESULT_OK;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (fileOutputStream != null) {
                try {
                    fileOutputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        publishResult(downloadedFile.getAbsolutePath(), 100, position, filesize <= 0);

    }

    private void publishResult(String downloadPath, int progress, int positionInList,
                               boolean indeterminable)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(INTENT_NOTIFICATION);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_PATH, downloadPath);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_PROGRESS, progress);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_POSITION, positionInList);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_INDETERMINABLE, indeterminable);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_RESULT, mResult);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
}
```

But still there is a download queue, no parallel downloads.

Comment: try out the Ion http library for android, its very simple to learn and use and all the requests generated using it create a separate thread for each network request automatically so you don't have to worry about downloading in parallel Ion will take care of it

Comment: @Bhargav, thanks for recommendation. I'll definitely have a look, but first, I'd like to try it without any library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run a task repeatedly on different sets of data, but you only need one execution running at a time, an `IntentService` suits your needs. To automatically run tasks as resources become available, or to allow multiple tasks to run at the same time (or both), you need to provide a managed collection of threads. To do this, use an instance of `ThreadPoolExecutor`, which runs a task from a queue when a thread in its pool becomes free. To run a task, all you have to do is add it to the queue.

**Reference:**
[Creating a Manager for Multiple Threads](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/create-threadpool.html)

Comment: Thanks for answer. I'd like to have multiple parallel tasks (downloads) running with ability to update UI. I'll have a look at ThreadPoolExecutor.

Comment: Maybe a silly newbie question, but do I need Service at all?

Comment: If you use service, you still will have to create threads within service for each download

Comment: try the sample in my reference link. I believe its a better approach in your case.

Comment: @PeterO. if that is your intention then I suggest using AsyncTask, all you have to do is call the download function in doInBackground() and any UI updates you want to do before/after in pre/postexecute() functions, so for every download you just instantiate a new DownloadAsyncTask and call execute on it

Comment: @PeterO, You will need to use a thread pool Executor to execute Asynctask . Default implementation uses a serial executor running on a single thread

So create a ThreadPoolExeecutor and then use

Asynctask's executeonExecutor instead of just execute method

Comment: @Bhargav, I didn't find AsyncTask a good approach for donwloading. It could take a while and if you rotate screen it has no Activity to update.

Comment: well imo threadpoolexecutor is the way to go using threads and handlers is overly complicated.